# Unix - Sort from child blocking

Tags: c, linux, pipe, system-calls

I was trying to complete an exercise when I found some problems that I cannot understand.
First one: 
I'm trying to sort a file using system(string), where the string contains: **/usr/bin/sort -n -o %s %s**. %s is the path which I read from the parent through a pipe, and printing the string I see that is correct. Everything seems working if I remove the -o %s. If I add it, the program gets stucked on the sort. 
Here the code:

```
str=strcat(dir, str);
printf("    %s       \n", str);
sprintf(ssys, "/usr/bin/sort -n -o %s %s", str, str);
printf("     1111    \n");
system(ssys);
printf("     2222   \n");
```

And the output is:

**/home/dio/Desktop/Operating-System-PoliTo/Lab6/ex2/texts/1.txt**

**1111**

As you can see, it doesn't reach the third printf, but just when I press CTRL+c to kill the process, even if the file isn't sorted. I cannot understand why, because if I run it and check with **ps** I get the **sort** process running.Seems like it is waiting for the parent to finish but it doesn't sort anyway.

This is the whole code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

static void sig_handler (int);

static void sig_handler (int signo)
{
        if (signo == SIGPIPE)
                exit(0);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{

        signal(SIGPIPE, sig_handler);

        if (argc<3)
        {
                printf("Too little arguments");
                return 1;
        }

        int c=atoi(argv[1]);
        int *pids=malloc(sizeof(int)*c);
        int i=0, num_char_str, id, line_sort, request_pipe[c][2], data_pipe[c][2], answer_pipe[c][2];
        pid_t pid;
        char cR, cW;
        char *dir=malloc(strlen(argv[2])+1);
        char *str=malloc(strlen(argv[2])*10);
        char *ssys=malloc(strlen(argv[2])*10);
        FILE* fpp;
        FILE* fp;

        strcpy(dir, argv[2]);
        sprintf(str, "ls %s > list.txt",  dir);
        system(str);
        for(i=0; i<c; i++)
        {
                if (pipe(request_pipe[i]) == -1)
                        return 2;
                if (pipe(data_pipe[i]) == -1)
                        return 2;
                if (pipe(answer_pipe[i]) == -1)
                        return 2;
        }
        for(i=0; i<c; i++)
        {
                pid=fork();
                if(pid>0)
                        pids[i]=pid;
                if (pid == -1)
                {
                        printf("error forking");
                        return 3;
                }
                if (pid==0)
                        break;
        }
    if (pid>0) /// parent
        {
                for(i=0; i<c; i++)
                {
                        close(answer_pipe[i][1]);  /// close answer pipe on writing
                        close(request_pipe[i][1]);  /// close request pipe on writing
                        close(data_pipe[i][0]);  /// close data pipe on reading
                }
                fp=fopen("list.txt", "r");
                if (fp==NULL)
                        return 3;
                i=0;
                while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp)!=NULL)
                {
                        /// wait for ask
                        read(request_pipe[i][0], &cR, 1);
                        /// sending first the number of characters to read
                        /// and then the file name
                        num_char_str=(strlen(str) +1);
                        write(data_pipe[i][1], &num_char_str, sizeof(int));
                        write(data_pipe[i][1], str, num_char_str);
                        /// read the answer
                        read(answer_pipe[i][0], &id, sizeof(int));
                        //pids[i]=id;
                        read(answer_pipe[i][0], &line_sort, sizeof(int));
                        if (i==c-1)
                                i=-1;
                        i++;
                }
                /// sending termination signal to children
                for (i=0; i<c; i++)
                        kill(pids[i], SIGPIPE);
                /// producing all_sorted.txt
                strcpy(str, "touch all_sorted.txt");
                system(str);
                sprintf(str, "find %s -name \"*.txt\" -exec cat \"{}\"\";\" > all_sorted.txt", dir);
                system(str);
                /// sorting all_sorted

        }
        if (pid == 0) /// child
        {
                close(answer_pipe[i][0]);  /// close answer pipe on reading
                close(request_pipe[i][0]);  /// close request pipe on reading
                close(data_pipe[i][1]);  /// close data pipe on writing
                while (1)
                {
                        /// send request to parent
                        write(request_pipe[i][1], &cW, 1);
                        /// read length of string
                        read(data_pipe[i][0], &num_char_str, sizeof(int));
                        /// read the file name
                        read(data_pipe[i][0], str, num_char_str);
                        /// sorting
                        str=strcat(dir, str);
                        sprintf(ssys, "/usr/bin/sort -n -o %s %s", str, str);
printf("     1111    \n");
                        system(ssys);
printf("     2222   \n");
                        /// sending back data
                        id=getpid(); 
                        write(answer_pipe[i][1], &id, sizeof(int));
                        //sprintf(str, "wc -l %s/%s", dir, str);
                        //fpp=popen(str, "r");
                        //fscanf(fpp, "%d", &line_sort);
                        //pclose(fpp);
                        line_sort=1;
                        write(answer_pipe[i][1], &line_sort, sizeof(int));
                }
        }

        return 0;

}
```

Comment: `sort` may be waiting for a EOF, or a closing of the stream being piped into it...

Comment: You should examine the file for which your `sort` seems to hang. Is it a regular file? Is it very big? Try to call `strace -fp <pid>` on the hanging process and look, on which call it is stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I didn't know about `strace`.
Btw seems the problem was the "\n" that fgets read and gave some problem to the sort call